How many edits (to other users' content) can a user make in a day?
Are there limitations on how many edits a user can make within a certain time range, like 24 hours? 
Also, is it possible not to pull questions with insignificant edits to the top on the main page? It is a bit annoying to see old questions "resurface" on the main page just because a user edits a few typos in the question description. It makes scanning for new questions and significant edits much harder. 
